# unable To connect in Node js

Tags: node.js, npm

I just started learning Node js, First I installed node,npm, express

I want to work in npm, but I don't know how to start. The command I gave in terminal was

```
 sh-4.2$ cd new/
 sh-4.2$ express new-project
 sh-4.2$ cd new/
 sh-4.2$ express new-project
 sh-4.2$ node app
```

But I was not able to connect in localhost:3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dislike automatic project generators so here is how to create a new express project manually.

Create new folder:

```
mkdir myNewApp
cd myNewApp
```

Create a new package.json (makes managing dependencies much easier) - just press enter to all questions, you can change these things later:

```
npm init
```

Install express and save it in our package.json:

```
npm install express --save
```

Create our main server file:

```
touch server.js
```

And paste the following:

```
var express = require('express'),
    server  = express();

server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('hello world');
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Now start it:

```
node server.js
```

And visit `http://localhost:3000` in your browser.

Comment: touch server.js is not reconised

Answer (score 2):

Try this command in your project folder after you've generated the project:

```
node bin/www
```

The code to run the server is placed in this file.

Comment: If the project has been generated, the recommended way to start is with `npm start`.